# Talend memory leak in tHashOutput/tHashInput

Tags: talend

I have a semi-slow memory leak in a Talend joblet. I am using a tHashOutput/tHashInput pair in the middle of a joblet because I need to find out how many rows are in the flow. Therefore, I push them into a tHashOutput and later on reference tHashOutput_1_NB_LINE from the globalMap.

[image: joblet flow]

I have what I think are the proper options:

- allRows - "append" is FALSE
- tHashinput_1 - "Clear after reading" is TRUE

Yet, when I run this for a period of time, and analyzing with the Eclipse Memory Analyzer, I see objects building up over time. This is what I get after 12 hours:

[image: memory usage]

This usage (64MB/12 hours) increases steadily and is unrelated to what the job is doing (i.e. actively pumping data or just idling - and this code while invoked for idling also). If I look inside the memory references in MAT, I can see strings that point me to this place in the code, like

tHashFile_DAAgentProductAccountCDC_delete_BPpuaT_jsonToDataPump_1_tHashOutput_2

(jsonToDataPump being the name of the joblet). Am I doing something wrong in using these hash components?

Answer (score 0):

i believe you should set your garbage collector pace to minimum time duration so that it will take care of unused object in application